# What does this sentence about toxemia and Clostridium tetani mean?

Tags: microbiology, pathogenesis

I know that Cl tetani is not invasive and strictly localised.
I think toxemia means spread in the blood.
I am thinking this sentence

> The volume of infected tissue is small, and the disease is almost entirely a toxemia.

Cl tetani has spores.
This suggests me that these spores spread through blood. 
They then open and become pathogenic in some tissues where they remain strictly locally (so small area/volume of infected tissue; I think area is better word, since the disease is not invasive) and pathogenic.

**How do you understand the quoted sentence about pathogenesis of Cl tetani?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Clostridium tetani* produces a protein toxin, [tetanospasmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetanospasmin) which causes the major symptom of tetanus, namely involuntary muscle spasms. *C. tetani* is an aerobic species, does not infect the blood, and apparently only produces toxin in anaerobic conditions.

If a pathogenic bacterium propagates through the bloodstream this condition is referred to as **bacteraemia**. In the case of *C. tetani* it is the toxin which enters the bloodstream, not the bacteria, hence **toxaemia**. The bacteria, being anaerobic, are inhibited from spreading through aerobic tissues.